# Visual Studio Keyboard shortcut to Error List when builds break

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Is there a keyboard shortcut to select/highlight the first error in the Error list on a failed build?

I would like to be able to quickly resolve missing namespaces as follows:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- [Magical keycombo to go to first error in error list][enter]
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>[enter]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try binding to `View.NextError` (it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> on my machine).

[image: VS options dialog]

Answer (score 20):

If you use Visual C# Development Settings <kbd>F8</kbd> takes you to the line of the next error on the list, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> moves you to the previous one.

Answer (score 7):

`View.ErrorList` in Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard. It's the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>\</kbd> , <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> chord on my machine. Pressing this chord automatically highlights the first error in the list, and then hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> goes to the code in question.

In previous defaults, the error list was shown with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> chord. To know for sure what it is in your setup, check the Options menu.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, the error list is given focus as soon as a build completes with errors, so you can just use the keyboard to navigate it.
Anyway, default shortcut to the list is ctrl + \, then ctrl + e. You can select any line with up/down and press enter to go there.

Comment: +1 This is good to know, but requires an uncomfortable shift of the arm to get all the way to the arrow keys.  My pinky can reach F12 alot easier as in Jon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful.

**Go to Tools-> Options**

1. In search Options (Ctrl+E) box,
   write Keyboard
2. In Show commands containing box,
   write **View.ErrorList**
3. In Shortcuts for selected command section, shortcut, that you need, will be appeared

[image]